# not able to add previous commit into github tag using workflow

Tags: github, tags, workflow, action, commit

I'm trying to push the previous commit into GitHub tags for rollback
I'm not able to store the previous commit, my code is pushing the latest commit to the github tags

User
name: Deploy to Azure Storage Account

on:
workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest

```
steps:
- name: Checkout repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Update Azure CLI
  run: |
    sudo apt-get install -y azure-cli

- name: Set up Azure CLI
  run: |
      npm ci

- name: Clear npm cache
  run: npm cache clean --force

- name: Log in to Azure
  run: |
    az login --service-principal --username ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} --password ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }} --tenant ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
    az account set --subscription ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}



- name: Set Git user identity
  run: |
      git config --global user.email ""
      git config --global user.name "Karandeep Singh"

- name: Store previous commit into tag
  env:
   GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
  run: |
    TAG_NAME="previous-commit-${GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER}"
    git tag -a $TAG_NAME $PREVIOUS_COMMIT -m "Tagging previous commit for run $GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER"
    git push origin $TAG_NAME --follow-tags

    
- name: Set up environment variables
  run: |
    touch .env
    echo "REACT_APP=testing1" > .env
    echo "REACT_APP_API_HOST=" >> .env
    echo "REACT_APP_AUTH_HOST=" >> .env
    echo REACT_APP="testing" >> .env
    npm run build


- name: Deploy to Azure Storage Account
  run: |
    az storage blob upload-batch --account-name ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME }} --account-key ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY }} --destination \$web --source ./build --debug --overwrite
```